# I have duplicate code - is there a way to extend/reuse terraform modules?

Tags: terraform, terraform-modules

I've copied and pasted large blocks of terraform, usually a sign to me that I'm missing some language feature that could neaten things up (relatively new to tf).

Example:

```
module "my_module"
{
   source = "../something"
   some_var = "a value"
   another_var = "another value"
   wow_more_var = "wow"
   a_module_specific_var = "1"
}

module "another_module"
{
   source = "../something"
   some_var = "a value"
   another_var = "another value"
   wow_more_var = "wow"
   a_module_specific_var = "2"
}
```

As you can see - the only way in which these module declarations differ are by the `a_module_specific_var` (at the end). Which language feature am I missing here that would allow me to abstract the common parts away? If this was in Node which is my usual arena, I'd pull this out into a JS function and just pass `1` or `2` as a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `count` or `for_each` with modules, documented [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/for_each.html). I would create a list containing those module specific vars, and then use `for_each`, like so:

```
module "my_module"
{
   for_each =  toset( ["1", "2"] )
   source = "../something"
   some_var = "a value"
   another_var = "another value"
   wow_more_var = "wow"
   a_module_specific_var = each.key
}
```

Comment: Nice! I was actually already aware of `for_each` but hadn't considered using it like this. Thank you.